# Why Aren't Deleted Documents Being Pruned When Optimizing InnoDB FullText Tables?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, full-text-search

Following the MySQL 5.6 [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-information-schema-fulltext_index-tables.html) (Example 14.5), I am under the impression that by setting `innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=1` and optimizing a table, both the `INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE` and `INNODB_FT_DELETED` should decrease (as DML gets "flushed"/"committed").

However, this is not the observed behavior; I have millions of "deleted" documents that are not being touched (and I am suffering an ever increasing performance hit for my fulltext searches).

```
MYSQL> SET GLOBAL innodb_optimize_fulltext_only=1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MYSQL> SET GLOBAL innodb_ft_aux_table = 'my_db/my_table'; 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MYSQL> select count(*) from INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      860 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MYSQL> select count(*) from INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6053404 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.63 sec)

MYSQL> select count(*) from INNODB_FT_DELETED;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6070724 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.63 sec)

MYSQL> OPTIMIZE TABLE my_db.my_table;
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+
| Table          | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+
| my_db.my_table | optimize | status   | OK       |
+----------------+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (5.30 sec)

MYSQL> select count(*) from INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MYSQL> select count(*) from INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6053404 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.96 sec)

MYSQL> select count(*) from INNODB_FT_DELETED;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  6070820 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.58 sec)
```

How can I get MySQL to take care of these deleted records?

Comment: Does "deleted" mean `DELETE`?  Or `SET deleted = 1`?

Comment: @RickJames after a DML `DELETE` is done, the docid is added to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_DELETED` before it is removed from the internal full text index structure.

Comment: Sounds like a bug report is needed here:  http://bugs.mysql.com